# Send data via GET to Server

Tags: android

I try to send data via GET to a server with a button.

The Url looks like this: `"http://192.168.4.1/?value=89"`.
But it doesn`t work. So may can somebody help me.

Comment: if you try the same request on browser, it works?

Comment: Have you tried this on your browser? If yes, what does it return?

Comment: Use `curl` with that same url to first see if you have a problem with android or a problem with your server. Your question right now is very vague.

Comment: Please provide more information than "doesn't work". Use the `logcat` command to capture the logs around the failure and post them with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the android.permission.INTERNET permission to your app's manifest.

```
Button mybutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button_id);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url ="http://192.168.4.1/?value=89";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Sucess
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Error
                }
            });
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
```